# passing a null datetime to reportparameter class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, nullable, reportparameter

How can I put a null value on datetime variable type?

I tried to make it nullable value, but I need to use it in `ReportParameter()` method to send it to my report but `ReportParameter()` constructor cannot take a nullable value and the ReportParameter() take just a string values!

Comment: Show the signature for `ReportParameter()` please.

Answer (score 2):

The various constructor overloads for [`ReportParameter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter#Constructors) only take in a string or string array as acceptable input.

[image: ReportParameter Constructor]

And the [`ReportParameter.Values`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter#Properties) property itself is actually a `StringCollection` in order to force the serialization to happen at compile time.

[image: ReportParameter Properties]

But you *can pass a null value* with string typing per this thread on [Passing NULL parameter from aspx page to Report Server](https://forums.asp.net/t/1113545.aspx?Passing+NULL+parameter+from+aspx+page+to+Report+Server) like this:

```
var rp = new ReportParameter("ServiceType_cd", new string[] { null });
```

Or per this question [Report Viewer: Set null value to Report Parameters having allow null true](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22625842/1366033), you can pass in a value like this:

```
string str = null;
var rp = new ReportParameter("ServiceType_cd", str));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create FailIfNull() extension method for this purpose. Please look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for more information about extension methods.